# How does JavaScript event function with parameters work?

Tags: javascript, events, parameters, global-variables, dom-events

After creating an object (graphical component) I add an event handler to it like that:

```
objects[text_identifier.toUpperCase()].on('mousedown tap', function(){enableDiagrams('Textfield', text_identifier, objects[text_identifier.toUpperCase()]);});
```

For example, if I have two objects. I have a function that shows all the attributes and its values from the object that is clicked. Here is a part of it:

```
function enableDiagrams(type, identifier, object) {
    currentType = type;
    currentIdentifier = identifier;
    ...
    document.getElementById('circle-identifier').value = currentIdentifier;
    ...
}
```

So I want to access the data of the individual object that I clicked on. If I click on my first object (created first), everything is displayed fine. Then I click on my second object, also fine. But if I click on the first item again now, the data from the second object is displayed.

I have to add that in my case it is necessary to deep copy the object after the display of the attributes. So after each display I have to declare the event handler again like this:

```
objects[currentIdentifier.toUpperCase()].on('mousedown tap', function(){enableDiagrams(type, currentIdentifier, objects[currentIdentifier.toUpperCase()]);});
```

(`currentType` and `currentIdentifier` are global variables)

So my guess is that my problem is about passing global variables to the declaration of the event function.

Can you explain me how this works?

Comment: its a bit hard to answer this shortly because I cant quite tell what the `text_identifier` object represents etc. . If you look carefully you are calling `enableDiagrams` inside your callback for `'mousedown tap'`, however the variables you pass to this function rely on data outside of this functions callback. The intended way is to leverage the function context of the `'mousedown tap'` event, such that in `function(obj){...}` you can either use the `this` context within it to refer to the object being tapped, or use the parameters that this function received.

Comment: text_identifier is just a local string here. I think it doesn't matter. But can you explain how the callback function works with global variables?

Comment: i have no clue where to start. The parameters from the `enableDiagrams` function will be resolved the moment the callback function is called (the parent `function(){}`). However your implementation looks a bit wonky because your `on()` event listener knows exactly which object is being listened to, so you have the object you need within the callback function if you use the `this` keyword. All you need is to set some properties on that object beforehand, so you dont have to pass `text_identifier.toUpperCase()` around.

Comment: Thanks, Flame! Let's say I have the information that I want pass in my `enableDiagrams` function stored in local variables, let's call them `var type = 'A String'`, `var identifier = 'Another String'`. So my result should look like this? `objects[identifier.toUpperCase()].on('mousedown tap', function(type, identifier, this){enableDiagrams(type, identifier, this);});`

Comment: If I do this it says `undefined`for using the `identifier`parameter.